# VC2010-WAMP fails to start OCI extension

Tags: wamp, wampserver, oracle9i, php-extension

Installed Last version of WAMP 2.2E 32bit on XP 32bit SP3 with VC 2010 redist.
Installation completed successfully.
But turning on the OCI8 and OCI8-11 extension fails by showing module not found !
Tried to copy the 2 dll files to SYSTEM32 and WINDOWS folder, still stuck. Though WAMP works perfectly except unable to use OCI functions.

- XP Pro XP SP3 32bit
- VC10 SP1 vcredist_x86.exe 32 bit
- Wampserver (32 bits & PHP 5.3) 2.2E

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of this page in the manual. [PHP OCI8 Installation requirements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/oci8.requirements.php)

Basicall you need to install some Oracle bits on the Client for these php_oci dlls to interface to.